# Element maybe inside frame from different src

Tags: python, selenium

Does anyone know what the message Element maybe inside frame from different src means?
I was trying to switch to frame and python selenium is not recognizing the element.
See screen shot of iframe path and message I see.

Below is what I see and getting timeout exception though page is loaded within waitime

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(E.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, 
'gsft_main')))


[![See below pic][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `ID` or `css selector`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(E.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 
'gsft_main')))
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(E.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
    'iframe#gsft_main')))
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(E.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
    'iframe[title="Main Content"]')))
```

Comment: None of them worked. I think this element is from different src. Not sure what that means and how to get xpath from different source.